# Can I conditionally turn certain oh-my-zsh plugins off?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

This is more of a long shot, but here we go:

I use oh-my-zsh with the vcs-plugins git and svn on. I now started on a project where it would be most convenient to use `sshfs`. The problem that now comes up with that is the following: the git plugin runs `git stat` after every command, which has a terrible performance in a directory mounted via `sshfs`. I know that I can determine with `df -TP . | grep 'fuse.sshfs'` whether I am in a sshfs directory.

I just don't know how/where to turn off the respective plugins. Is there a better way than directly altering the `git-prompt.plugin.zsh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "plugin" in OMZ is just a script. You can't disable part of it without modifying the script.

A workaround would be to use [Antigen](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen) or [Zgen](https://github.com/tarjoilija/zgen), copy the script to some other location, modify it accordingly, and load it as a separate bundle. Both Antigen and Zgen are designed to support OMZ so you won't have to change anything substantive in your setup.

Comment: Though this comes near to a "not possible", I'll accept… too bad though.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. for years I've been wanting to break up both OMZ and Prezto into standalone scripts with specified dependencies, and then fork a lighter-than-Antigen package manager (probably Zgen or Zilsh) to handle it. One day I'll find the time...